# Publishing Desktop Application through Ftp Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, desktop-application, setup-deployment

i am trying to publish my desktop application over server through ftp "ftp://xxx.xx.X.xx/myapplication" but its published file are always going into different folder rather than publishing into myapplication folder. Can anybody have an idea why is this happening ??

Answer (score 1):

Application was publishing to different folder because there was no ftp site for my application , i created ftp site for "myapplication" with the port and it published successfully. Hope it will help someone

Thanks